# Only buzzing sound while playing wav file through QAudioOutput

Tags: c++, windows, qt, audio

Using Qt 5.5.1 on a Windows 7 desktop and a laptop.

I can only hear the buzzing sound, nothing else. Please guide.

Link to the wav file, I tried - 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/frfy43d8hznptgf/c.wav?dl=0

I have tried this with mp3 files also. All I get is buzzing sound.

**The reproducable example:**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QAudioOutput* audioOutpu;

    QFile sourceFile;
    sourceFile.setFileName("c.wav");
    bool p = sourceFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    if (p == false)
        qDebug() << "no file";
    else
        qDebug() << "yes file";


    QAudioDeviceInfo d1;
    QList<QAudioDeviceInfo> l1 = d1.availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput);

    qDebug() << "======================================================";
    qDebug() << l1.first().supportedCodecs();
    qDebug() << l1.first().supportedChannelCounts();
    qDebug() << l1.first().supportedSampleTypes();
    qDebug() << l1.first().supportedSampleRates();
    qDebug() << l1.first().supportedSampleSizes();

    QAudioFormat desiredFormat1;
    desiredFormat1.setChannelCount(2);
    desiredFormat1.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    desiredFormat1.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    desiredFormat1.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
    desiredFormat1.setSampleRate(44100);
    desiredFormat1.setSampleSize(16);

    QAudioDeviceInfo info1(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
    if (!info1.isFormatSupported(desiredFormat1))
    {
           qWarning() << "Default format not supported, trying to use the nearest.";
           desiredFormat1 = info1.preferredFormat();
    }

    audioOutpu = new QAudioOutput(desiredFormat1);
    audioOutpu->setVolume(1.0);

    audioOutpu->start(&sourceFile);
    qDebug() << "bbbbbbbbbb";
    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(audioOutpu, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    do {
        loop.exec();
    } while(audioOutpu->state() == QAudio::ActiveState);

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: a link to the wav file would be great.

Comment: how would i do that? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: I admit would would have to link to an external link like dropbox

Comment: I have just tested your code on some `.wav`, and it played fine.

Comment: On a laptop or desktop? @Mike Do you think it can be computer specific?

Comment: You should include your whole configuration description, a link (dropbox for example) to the buzzy wav file

Comment: @ThomasAyoub as I said before every file produces buzzing sound with this program.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius , I tried it on a laptop running Qt5.6.1 on windows 7 if that matters, and there was no problem at all. . .

Comment: Had you replied  earlier,  I wouldn't have raised a bounty. @Mike

Comment: sorry, I forgot to reply, but did that solve your problem??!

Comment: @Mike I tried it with Qt 5.5.1 on a windows 7 laptop, and all I could hear was a buzzing sound.

Comment: So did you try updating QT since Mike is clearly running a newer version? I give it a low chance that it will matter, but this is a process of elimination before there is going to be a solution.

Comment: @Gimby that's what I didn't try since this feature is since Qt 4.8! But I will try with newer version soon. Can you do me a favor by trying it on your computer also, please?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius , and maybe it is related to the WAV files you are testing with then, please try uploading a sample WAV file so that we can all test it. . .

Comment: @Mike i will definitely do it now. I am sick of all this.

Comment: @Mike added the link to wav file.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius , if I use your code, your WAV file produces buzzing sound here too. I am looking into the problem and I'll come back if I find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your wav file is not really [WAVE format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV), here is [MediaInfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaInfo) output associated with the file:

```
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 4.67 MiB
Duration                                 : 5mn 6s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 128 Kbps
Track name                               : Careless  Whisper
Performer                                : Kenny G
Genre                                    : Instrumental

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Mode                                     : Joint stereo
Mode extension                           : MS Stereo
Duration                                 : 5mn 6s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 4.67 MiB (100%)
```

it is MPEG Audio compressed file and that's why you can't use `"audio/pcm"` codec to play it, I uncompressed your audio file into PCM, and your code was able to play it right. Here is what MediaInfo outputs with my file:

```
Format                                   : Wave
File size                                : 51.6 MiB
Duration                                 : 5mn 6s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 1 411 Kbps

Audio
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : 1
Duration                                 : 5mn 6s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 411.2 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 51.6 MiB (100%)
```

If you need to play compressed audio formats, consider using [`QMediaPlayer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html), have a look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/audiooverview.html#playing-compressed-audio).

Comment: Thanks much. I was not able to play flac also with this program. Can you shed some light on that too?

Comment: you're welcome, [FLAC Audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC) is another codec for lossless **compression** of audio, so what can be used to play uncompressed PCM audio can NOT be used to uncompress and play FLAC. Again consider using `QMediaPlayer`.

Comment: Much thanks again. I also intend to receive audio from usb frame grabber and have it played. What do you suggest for that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by usb frame grabber, maybe I can help if you provide more details. . .

Comment: A micro phone is attached to the usb frame grabber. It is detected in Windows as: "Line (2 - USB Device)"

Comment: Does it show up in "Recoding Devices" (Control Panel -> sound)? If so, I don't think you need to be using anything related to usb, you can just start recording from it as if it is a normal microphone, try running the [Audio Recorder Example](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtmultimedia-audiorecorder-example.html), it should be able to capture sound if the device shows up under recording devices. . .

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius , if does not show up. I'm sorry, I have no idea how such devices work.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't suggest this program http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtmultimedia-audioinput-example.html  is this  supposed to play the sound received from the microphone? Or I am barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius , both examples work for your case, I just wanted to make sure you are getting audio from your usb device.